# Is there a way to know the exact number of devices the Ionic Deploy was applied to?

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework

I'm using [Ionic Deploy service](http://docs.ionic.io/docs/deploy-overview) and I'm wondering if it's possible to see (at least approximately) on how many devices the deploy was applied?

Reason behind all this is that some clients/testers report that they're not seeing an update, whereas other report getting it just fine...

I know that Ionic Deploy is [still in beta](http://docs.ionic.io/docs/deploy-overview) and it could be it's limited to a certain amount of devices?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The official response which I got from the Ionic team on twitter was that they do not support this in Beta. It may, however, come once they go live. Wait and see...